# Access synchronization from failed Camel Exchange

Tags: java, activemq-classic, apache-camel

I would like to access all the Synchronization's that were added to an exchange during a camel route.

The reason for this is that when a particular type of exception happens, I want to route the message to an error handling component and let that error handling component execute the "onCompletion" of those synchronizations even though there was an exception.

the synchronizations are added by using

```
exchange.getUnitofWork().addSynchronization(new MySyncAdapter());
```

and I was trying to access them with

```
exchange.handoverCompletions();
```

However, I think I must be doing something wrong because no matter which component I try to get the completions from (my real component, or the error component), the list is null.

Edit:

According tot he answer below, this should work:

```
exchange.addOnCompletion(new MySyncAdapter());
List<Synchronization> syncs = exchange.handoverCompletions();
```

however, syncs is still null. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Exchange in this case does not have the Completions/Synchronizations, the UnitOfWork instance does so when you call `exchange.handoverCompletions()` you will get a null.  You also do not have access to the synchronizations in the UnitOfWork because it is being handled in a different thread. Any attempt to modify them, which is what handoverCompletion does, causes a concurrency exception.

In reality you are trying to use something in a way it wasn't intended.  Exchange errors should be handled by invoking the Exception Clause DSL outlined [here](http://camel.apache.org/exception-clause.html).  It is designed to capture exchange errors in a fine grained manner by allowing a developer to define the Exception type and forward the Exchange to a route for further processing by your error handling component.

Best Regards,
Scott ES

Comment: I tried this as well. I added the example in the edits. syncs is still null

Comment: What version are you using?  I just wrote a simple unit test against trunk and it passed as expected.

Comment: We're using 2.6 here. I did a little looking around, and tried to debug with the camel source. It appears that it will work the way you suggested only if I set the exchange's unit of work to null. Should that be the case? Are there any other side effects?

Comment: Let me dig a little deeper first.  That doesn't sound correct.

Comment: Ok. JUst so you know too, I think I am going to have to stick with using a UnitOfWork for this anyway. It would appear that if I have several processors, and I add synchronizations to the exchange in each of them, the exchange.handoverCompletions() will only give me the ones from that processor, not from the previous processors that run.

Comment: Whereas if I am using a UnitOfWork to add the synchronizations, all of them are available in all the processors, however, I have to hand them over to a temporary exchange, then get the exchange to do the handover in order to access them

Comment: Thanks for all the details.  After this exchange and rereading your comment see above.

Comment: I read your updated answer - and that's about what I figured. Thanks.  Regards to paragraph 2,  I am using the Exception clause DSL. However, all I am doing there is setting some flags on the message, and then forwarding the message to a Queue that is read by my error handling component. That error handling component is the one I am trying to give access to the synchronizations, so that it can, say, retry a particular processor, and if succesful, fire off the onCompletions, or if it fails, fire the onFailures that were set up in the other processors on the original component.

Comment: I am not sure I am completely following you but it sounds as if you just want to reuse the logic in the original route processor.  If that is accurate and assuming your Synchronization logic is abstracted, just inject that Class into both the processor.